# Keyboard shortcut swap/move individual desktop spaces

Tags: keyboard, desktop, spaces, mission-control

I tend to just use one "Desktop" Desktop, then my other Desktops are full-screened apps. I frequently close & open Desktop spaces, like when I decide to open a new browser window.

My question is: How can I swap the Desktop spaces around with just keyboard shortcuts? Currently, it can only be done by going to Mission Control and clicking & dragging the space.

A third-party suggestion would be fine. I tried Spectacles and SizeUp, and neither can do this. SizeUp can only move a window into the next Desktop, not move the whole thing.

Comment: Can you be more specific what exactly "How can I swap the Desktop spaces around with just keyboard shortcuts" mean? What do you want to do?

Comment: It is the same functionality as going to Mission Control and clicking & dragging the space. For example, I have three Desktops (desktop, discord, firefox), and I want to change the order (desktop, firefox, discord).